# How do you remove the Unicode character U+2B9 error?

Tags: errors, unicode, input-encodings

Every time I try to compile and run my Latex document I get the following error:

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ʹ (U+2B9)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.

even though I have nothing written on the line that the error is appearing on. Does anyone know how to remove this error?

Thanks!

Below I've included my preamble and an empty document which when I compile still gives that message.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\date{}
\title{}
\author{}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{inputenc}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}



\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{eg}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{rk}{Remark}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\maketitle


\tableofcontents
\pagebreak


\pagebreak
\bibliography{Biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add your MWE (Minimal Working Example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode 2b9 is "modifier letter prime", which looks almost like an apostrophe.  Most likely, you copy and pasted your text from something that was "helpfully" making smart quotes for you.  Find the smart apostrophe and replace it with a regular apostrophe.

If your posted example is truly your tex file, then the problem is in one of your supplementary files.  Delete the auxiliary files and compile again, and look through your bibliography for a smart quote that snuck in when you copied the reference from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when I had a reference with an author whose last name included this symbol. I decided to cope with the error by putting the following in my preamble:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02B9}{'}
```

Perhaps someone more familiar with Russian last names than I am could comment if a different substitute character would be more appropriate.

Comment: For the Math Reviews transliteration of cyrillic names, this definition has been used: `\def\cprime{\/{\mathsurround=0pt$'$}}`.  This produces an actual prime, not an apostrophe.